# Reading CSV files from the command line and running a python script from the command line

Tags: python, pandas, shell, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read in multiple .csv files from the command line and I want to take those .csv files and turn them into pandas `DataFrame` Objects. I then want to take those data frame objects and pass them to function that does operations on the data the `DataFrames` contain. I am familiar with python `csv` and `sys` modules and was wondering where I could I look for more information about how to read .csv files from the command line

Currently, I am using Jupyter Notebooks to process my .csv files into `DataFrame` Objects and then pass the `DataFrame` objects to my function. This method works, but I have hundreds of files that I have to process and I don't want be modifying the jupyter notebook every time for each file change.

Comment: Just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147518/how-to-automate-python-script-written-in-jupyter-notebook#comment100810356_57147518) and now your question. Hmm!

Comment: Are you asking how to run a python script from the commandline or how to write a python script that iterates over your files?

Comment: Maybe you should tag this with [jupyter notebook].  Anyways, you can't provide values to a notebook via the command line, since that is meant for the server, not the notebook.  So you need to convert the notebook(s) to regular Python scripts.  Or try to load this list of filenames from some other file.

Comment: I'm trying to stop using jupyter notebooks to read my csv files into DataFrame objects and instead use python from the command line like this: **python3 graph.py file1.csv file2.csv** to generate my graphs

Comment: This is what I'm trying to figure out how to implement: 1) command line: **python3 graph.py file1.csv file2.csv** 2) graph.py description: foo_1 = pandas.read_csv(file1.py) foo_2 = pandas.read_csv(file2.csv) graph_func (foo_1, foo_2): do some stuff with the data frames and generate a web page containing graphs

Comment: To add command line arguments, take a look at Python's argparse module. You can add required or optional arguments to the command line.